# Bisection search not working in my python code

Tags: python, search, bisection

I am trying to find best savings rate per month using bisection search with given semi annual raise and rate of return on investment. The code runs on infinite loop.

```
# cost of the house 
total_cost = 1000000
portion_down_payment = 0.25 * total_cost
current_savings = 0
annual_salary = int(input("enter your starting salary: "))
starting_salary = annual_salary / 12

semi_annual_raise = 0.07
# annual rate of return on investment is 4%
inv_rate = 0.04 / 12
months = 0
low = 0
high = 10000
number_steps = 0
# finding current savings using  Bisection search
while abs((current_savings*36) - portion_down_payment) >= 100:
    number_steps += 1
    starting_salary = annual_salary / 12
    for months in range(1, 37):
        current_savings += (starting_salary * inv_rate)
# semi annual raise of 7 %
        if months % 6 == 0:
            starting_salary += starting_salary * 0.07

    if current_savings * 36 < portion_down_payment:
        low = current_savings
    else:
        high = current_savings
    current_savings = (high + low) / 2
print("number of steps taken by bisection search is :", number_steps)
# printing savings rate 
print(current_savings / starting_salary)
```

Comment: do you have to implement it from scratch or using built-in `bisect` is an option?

Comment: I cannot use  other than loops

Comment: also, why do you think this is a bisect search?

Comment: bisection search is assuming low and high and then finding answer in between

Comment: [bisect search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_(software_engineering)) takes a sorted input and then iteratively cuts it in half, removing irrelevant part until only one element remains. I do not see any resemblance with the code here. Are we talking about the same problem?

Comment: yes , I am trying to do the same here

Comment: so what is the sorted input and what is the search element?

Comment: i did work on my machine: Output: \n enter your starting salary: 1000
number of steps taken by bisection search is: 9
55.51836450752423

Comment: Ah, I got it. Sorry for my ignorance. You're talking about a [numerical method to find parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), not [array search method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_(software_engineering)).

Comment: Answer for starting salary 150,000 is 12 steps:) I am going really wrong but I just trying figure it out

Comment: @RiteshPurohit Do you intend to reinitialize the starting salary in each iteration?

Comment: The biggest issue: variables do not have clear definitions. What is `current_savings`? It is a derivative of high and low but then compared to portion downpayment. investment rate is used to get interest on salary instead of savings etc. Just giving a clear definition to each variable and walking through the code should help.

Comment: It doesn't stop because current_savings grows while portion_down_payment is constant.